# AMD 19.30 driver on Ubuntu Server 18.04.3

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I just installed fresh 18.04.3 server, did apt dist-upgrade, downloaded AMD driver v19.30-855429, running install script ... and

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.98-855429)
            Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.98-855429)
            Depends: libllvm9.0-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:9.0-855429)
            Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 (= 1.15.0-855429)
            Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 (= 1.15.0-855429)
            Depends: libwayland-amdgpu-egl1:i386 (= 1.15.0-855429)
            Depends: libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-mesa-drivers:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libgles1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: libosmesa6-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: mesa-amdgpu-va-drivers:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
            Depends: mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 (= 1:19.2.0-855429)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

A bit confusing since they claim it supports 18.04.3, or it works only on Desktop version ? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-add-repository universe && sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update`, then run your original script.

Comment: Why do you need AMD drivers on a server?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` solved the issue.